# Showing that $Det(A^T A)\ge 0$

Tags: linear-algebra

How would it be shown this is property of determinants.

Showing that $Det(A^T A)\ge 0$

My reason:

It is know that $Det(A^T)=det(A)$

and by the multiplicative property it is know $Det(A^T A)=Det(A)Det(A^T)$

this equivalent to

$det(A)det(A)=det(A)^2$

and $det(A)^2 \ge 0$

End.

Would this be correct.

Comment: $A^T$ is switch the rows and columns of matrix A.

Comment: $det(A)det(A) = det(A)^2$

Comment: @aram yes I that is an important detail

Comment: No I have edited my post.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. You should only replace "$\det(A^T) =A$" by "$\det(A^T)=\det(A)$".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use these results:

$$\det(A^T)=\det(A)$$
and
$$\det(AB)=\det(A)\det (B)$$

Comment: He already knew this